# Summation variables aren't recognised as dummy variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation, vector-calculus, indexed-variable, indexing

I'm trying to write this expression[image]

in Mathematica, and calculate the following quantity

[image]

However, when I tried the following

```
Clear[g, n, v,T,P,B,r,i,j,k,l,t,w,Q,g,a,f]
g = B*(Sum[Indexed[n, k]*Log[Indexed[n, k]*Indexed[v, k]],k])+ Sum[Indexed[n, f]*Indexed[w, f],f] + Sum[Sum[0.5*Indexed[Indexed[Q, l], j]*Indexed[n, l]*Indexed[n, j],j],l] + P;
a = Indexed[v, r] * (g - Sum[D[g, Indexed[n, t]]*Indexed[n, t],t]) + D[g,Indexed[n, r]]
Collect[a,B] //Simplify
```

If I run `Clear[g]` right before `a`, I basically get

$$v_r * g$$

as a result of the computation and the reason is that it calculates the derivatives of $g$ wrt $n_k$s as exactly zero. Meaning that it doesn't recognise the summation indices as dummy indices.

How can I correct my code such that the dummy summation variables will be a dummy and hence I'll be able to perform the above calculation correctly?

**Addedum:**
If you get the following result when you run the code
$$v_r \left(B \sum _k n_k \log (n_k v_k)+\sum _f n_f w_f+\sum _l \left(\sum _j 0.5 n_j n_l Q_{l\, j}\right)+P\right)$$
it means that the code is not computing what is needs to compute because this is a wrong answer. For example, if you put `Clear[g]` right before the definition of `a` in the code, you can see that during the calculation of `a`, all the derivatives of $g$ wrt $\eta_k$ are taken as zero.

Comment: It is working as expected in v12.2.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I run the code on the cloud, it didn't.

Comment: @AlexTrounev And I've just tried on v12.2; the derivatives of $g$ wrt the indexed variables are still zero. Do note that the answer $v_r g$ is a wrong answer.

Comment: Works properly for me in 12.2 on Windows 10 Pro, producing $$ v_r \left(B \sum _k n_k \log (n_k v_k)+\sum _f n_f w_f+\sum _l \left(\sum _j 0.5 n_j n_l Q_{l\, j}\right)+P\right).$$. The cloud machine is running on Linux.

Comment: @user64494 that is not the correct answer, that is what I'm saying

Comment: @AlexTrounev see the addedum

Comment: @user64494 please see my addedum